# Determine if a given integer number is element of the Fibonacci sequence in C without using float

Tags: c, floating-point, integer, fibonacci, integer-division

I had recently an interview, where I failed and was finally told having not enough experience to work for them.

The position was embedded C software developer. Target platform was some kind of very simple 32-bit architecture, those processor does not support floating-point numbers and their operations. Therefore double and float numbers cannot be used.

The task was to develop a C routine for this architecture. This **takes one integer and returns whether or not that is a Fibonacci number**. However, from the memory **only an additional 1K temporary space is allowed to use** during the execution. That means: even if I simulate very great integers, I can't just build up the sequence and interate through.

As far as I know, a positive integer is a exactly then a Fibonacci number if one of

> (5n ^ 2) + 4

or

> (5n ^ 2) − 4

is a perfect square. Therefore I responded the question: it is simple, since the routine must determine whether or not that is the case.

They responded then: on the current target architecture no floating-point-like operations are supported, therefore no square root numbers can be retrieved by using the stdlib's `sqrt` function. It was also mentioned that basic operations like division and modulus may also not work because of the architecture's limitations.

Then I said, okay, we may build an array with the square numbers till 256. Then we could iterate through and compare them to the numbers given by the formulas (see above). They said: this is a bad approach, even if it would work. Therefore they did not accept that answer.

Finally I gave up. Since I had no other ideas. I asked, what would be the solution: they said, it won't be told; but advised me to try to look for it myself. My first approach (the 2 formula) should be the key, but the square root may be done alternatively.

I googled at home a lot, but never found any "alternative" square root counter algorithms. Everywhere was permitted to use floating numbers.

For operations like division and modulus, the so-called "integer-division" may be used. But what is to be used for square root?

Even if I failed the interview test, this is a very interesting topic for me, to work on architectures where no floating-point operations are allowed.

Therefore my questions:

1. How can floating numbers simulated (if only integers are allowed to use)?
2. What would be a possible soultion in C for that mentioned problem? Code examples are welcome.

Comment: Why can't you calculate the numbers in a Fibonacci sequence in 1K memory? You don't have to store all the numbers.

Comment: @Ajay Brahmakshatriya: I also asked it, as it was told. They said: it would be too simple and the bad approach to the/their solution. I guess maybe because of performance issues.

Comment: You can calculate the square root on an integer using [this](http://www.math-only-math.com/square-root-of-a-perfect-square-by-using-the-long-division-method.html) method.

Comment: @Ajay Brahmakshatriya: division and modulus operators were not allowed to be used.

Comment: This technique does not require division or modulo, just multiplication and subtraction.

Comment: As there are only 46 Fibonacci numbers < 2^32, you could precompute and store them in 184 bytes.

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth: you are right. But for me it would be interesting how you "simulate" floating-numbers.

Comment: @A.V.: Of course, anything can be simulated, but I bet that is not the answer they wanted. In any case, you can take a look at how libraries like http://flip.gforge.inria.fr/ do it :-)

Comment: Note: "... those processor does not support floating-point numbers and their operations. Therefore double and float numbers cannot be used." --> All processors can support FP C types.  Some compilers simply do not. It is not because the processors lacks ability.  It is a compiler limitation.

Comment: This may help [Integer square root, Using bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root#Using_bitwise_operations)

Comment: @chux: I do not agree with you. Since there are CPUs with no FPU. On those software-implemented floating point routines may exist. And exactly that was the point in that test. I did and do not know how you do this in pure C.

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps rather than disagreeing, state details of doubt and avoid generalities.  Perhaps after 40+ years of doing C and working with CPUs, my understanding of them is incorrect and yours is correct.  Good luck on next interview.

Comment: I would expect given the algorithm [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root#Using_bitwise_operations), a successful new programmer would be able to code `int  isqrt(int)`  in C, without further assistance.  Take a try at it - it is not too hard.

Comment: @chux: “Support … types” is generally used to mean there is specific hardware support for the types, not merely that the processor is Turing complete for practical purposes. Whichever you meant is not clear from your comment, and you have not clarified it.

Comment: @A.V. You can easily just build up the sequence and iterate through it.  There are only 46 Fibonacci numbers that fit in 32 bits, totaling 184 bytes, and 92 numbers that fit in 64 bits, totaling 736 bytes.  So you have enough room to store them all, and you can do a binary search in 7 iterations or less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of this type of interview is to see how you approach new problems. If you happen to already know the answer, that is undoubtedly to your credit but it doesn't really answer the question. What's interesting to the interviewer is watching you grapple with the issues.

For this reason, it is common that an interviewer will add additional constraints, trying to take you out of your comfort zone and seeing how you cope.

I think it's great that you knew that fact about recognising Fibonacci numbers. I wouldn't have known it without consulting Wikipedia. It's an interesting fact but does it actually help solve the problem?

Apparently, it would be necessary to compute `5n²±4`, compute the square roots, and then verify that one of them is an integer. With access to a floating point implementation with sufficient precision, this would not be too complicated. But how much precision is that? If `n` can be an arbitrary 32-bit signed number, then `n²` is obviously not going to fit into 32 bits. In fact, `5n²+4` could be as big as 65 bits, not including a sign bit. That's far beyond the precision of a `double` (normally 52 bits) and even of a `long double`, if available. So computing the precise square root will be problematic.

Of course, we don't actually need a precise computation. We can start with an approximation, square it, and see if it is either four more or four less than `5n²`. And it's easy to see how to compute a good guess: it will very close to `n×√5`. By using a good precomputed approximation of `√5`, we can easily do this computation without the need for floating point, without division, and without a sqrt function. (If the approximation isn't accurate, we might need to adjust the result up or down, but that's easy to do using the identity `(n+1)² = n²+2n+1`; once we have `n²`, we can compute `(n+1)²` with only addition.

We still need to solve the problem of precision, so we'll need some way of dealing with 66-bit integers. But we only need to implement addition and multiplication of positive integers, is considerably simpler than a full-fledged bignum package. Indeed, if we can prove that our square root estimation is close enough, we could safely do the verification modulo 2³¹.

So the analytic solution can be made to work, but before diving into it, we should ask whether it's the best solution. One very common caregory of suboptimal programming is clinging desperately to the first idea you come up with even when as its complications become increasingly evident. That will be one of the things the interviewer wants to know about you: how flexible are you when presented with new information or new requirements.

So what other ways are there to know if `n` is a Fibonacci number. One interesting fact is that if `n` is `Fib(k)`, then `k` is the floor of `logφ(k×√5 + 0.5)`. Since `logφ` is easily computed from `log2`, which in turn can be approximated by a simple bitwise operation, we could try finding an approximation of `k` and verifying it using the classic `O(log k)` recursion for computing `Fib(k)`. None of the above involved numbers bigger than the capacity of a 32-bit signed type.

Even more simply, we could just run through the Fibonacci series in a loop, checking to see if we hit the target number. Only 47 loops are necessary. Alternatively, these 47 numbers could be precalculated and searched with binary search, using far less than the 1k bytes you are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely an interviewer for a programming position would be testing for knowledge of a specific property of the Fibonacci sequence. Thus, unless they present the property to be tested, they are examining the candidate’s approaches to problems of this nature and their general knowledge of algorithms. Notably, the notion to iterate through a table of squares is a poor response on several fronts:

- At a minimum, binary search should be the first thought for table look-up. Some calculated look-up approaches could also be proposed for discussion, such as using find-first-set-bit instruction to index into a table.
- Hashing might be another idea worth considering, especially since an efficient customized hash might be constructed.
- Once we have decided to use a table, it is likely a direct table of Fibonacci numbers would be more useful than a table of squares.

Comment: @rici: Updated.